# How to develop app only for the Lumia devices?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, nokia, lumia

I see more apps on the Windows Phone depends on the Phone Model.

GroupOn, Nokia apps, App folder are some of the apps I mean. I can only install these apps if I've Lumia Phone. Else I can't install.

Like that, I wish to develop an app only for the Lumia devices. How could I develop ?

Answer (score 1):

Manufacturers and operators have the ability to add apps either when devices are provisioned or via separate app stores.

You'll need to work with the manufacturer to set this up.
This is normally done for apps they've developed themselves or have some kind of exclusivity deal with the app. They don't have public ways for developers to request this.

There's no way to release an app in the store and make it only available to specific devices. I've seen a few apps that are intended for only a few devices with comments in the store description to indicate this but there's no way to stop people with other devices installing - and inevitably leaving bad reviews.

Why would you want to limit your potential user base anyway? Especially when non-Nokia devices are less than 10% of the market anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find it very difficult to get your app for download by device only without working with the OEM to get your app into their own collection on the Store.

If you're thinking of making your app Nokia only, get in touch with the Nokia Developer Program and see if you can get in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to ask that only Nokia user can see your app other user can't like Samsung or HTC then you can't there is chance if QA team pass your code.........

try to access device info (line name) 
if you found device name Lumia then open your application else just exit from application

```
private void initialize(object sender)
{
        string deviceDetails = "Device detail";
        deviceDetails += DeviceStatus.DeviceName + ",";

        MessageBox.Show(deviceDetails);
        //to know whether device supports smooth streaming of multi resolution video
        if (deviceDetails.equals("..your supportes device 1..") || deviceDetails.equals("..your supportes device 2.."))
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Supported");
             //open application go further
        }
        else
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Not supported");
              //close your application
        }

}
```

Comment: This will happen after the user installed my application on their phone. I don't want to code like this. Only Lumia users have the ability to install my app on their phone. See, You can't install Nokia Camera app on the Samsung devices. Like that, I wish to develop my app.!

Comment: I am MICROSOFT Partner,believe me you just put this type of functionality and while you upload it to the store there is a not for tester from developer side over there you can write that I made this app only for Nokia device so tested on it. So if your application make up to the mark then it is possible they release your application with in Nokia Store, it self so only Nokia user can see it. if you are using Nokia device then you might you that while you open Store there are several options like Nokia Apps, Apps, Games, SD Card.etc they put your app inside that. I hope this will helpful to you